# Why is this code being generated by avr-gcc and how does it work?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, assembly, avr, avr-gcc

This is a snippet of disassembled AVR code from a C project I'm working on. I noticed this curious code being generated, and I can't understand how it works. I'm assuming it's some sort of ridiculous optimization...

What is the explanation?

```
92:         ticks++;         // unsigned char ticks;
+0000009F:   91900104    LDS       R25,0x0104     Load direct from data space
+000000A1:   5F9F        SUBI      R25,0xFF       Subtract immediate
+000000A2:   93900104    STS       0x0104,R25     Store direct to data space
95:         if (ticks == 0) {
+000000A4:   2399        TST       R25            Test for Zero or Minus
+000000A5:   F009        BREQ      PC+0x02        Branch if equal
+000000A6:   C067        RJMP      PC+0x0068      Relative jump
```

Specifically, why does the second instruction subtract 0xFF from R25 instead of just `INC R25`?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, I'm referring to the second line: Subtract 0xFF from R25... why not just "INC R25" ?

Comment: as pointed out by @PeterCordes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337831/why-is-this-code-being-generated-by-avr-gcc-and-how-does-it-work/1337882?noredirect=1#comment62982826_1337882 - code like this gets emitted virtually **only** with `-O0`, making the question itself a bit moot... with `-O3`/`-Os`, those instructions would get changed into more compact versions (branch on flags etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SUBI instruction can be used to add/subtract any 8 bit constant to/from an 8 bit value. It has the same cost as INC, i.e. instruction size and execution time. So SUBI is preferred by the compiler because it is more general. There is no corresponding ADDI instruction, probably because it would be redundant.

Comment: you're right that both have the same size/CPU clocks - yet saying "`SUBI` is preferred (...) because it is more general" is just handwaving without describing any specifics; `SUBI` ain't "more general", because it requires registers r16-31 instead of the the `INC`'s r0-31 range. avr-gcc compiler was *hand-tuned* to do `SUBI` instead of `INC`, for the very reason given by Greg below - `SUBI` sets the carry flag properly, whereas `INC` just ignores it. It makes 16/32-bit counters much simpler with `SUBI`, because you don't have to check lower bytes for overflow at all!

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** the compiler was designed to use the more portable, efficient & general solution here.

The [`SUBI`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_SUBI.html) instruction sets `C` (carry) and `H` (half-carry) CPU flags for use with subsequent instructions (there is no `ADDI` in 8-bit AVR BTW, so to add an immediate value of `x` we subtract `-x` from it), whereas [`INC`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_INC.html) does not. Since both `SUBI` & `INC` have 2 bytes of length and execute during 1 clock cycle, you lose nothing by using `SUBI` - OTOH, if you use a 8-bit-sized counter, you can then easily detect if it has rolled over (by [`BRCC`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_BRCC.html)/[`BRCS`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_BRCS.html)), and if you'd have a 16- or 32-bit-sized counter, it allows you to increment it in a very simple way - with just `INC`, `0x00FF` would get increased to `0x0000`, so you'd have to check if the lowest byte is `0xFF` before `INC`ing. OTOH, with `SUBI` you just `SUBI -1` the lowest byte, and then `ADC 0` for the following bytes, assuring all the potential carry bits has been accounted for.

Further reading:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/avr-gcc-list/2008-11/msg00029.html

http://avr-gcc-list.nongnu.narkive.com/SMMzdBkW/foo-subi-vs-inc

Comment: I included the next few instructions... does that help narrow things down? I still don't get the point of "SUBI R25,0xFF" vs. "INC R25", both are 1 clock. And if R25 rolls over from 255 to 0, the the TST R25 instruction would work just fine.

Comment: Ok. I thought this through a bit and realized that in unsigned math, subtracting 0xFF is the same as adding 0x01. Wierd, but why do it this way? Does INC not set flags for the branch?

Comment: It looks like INC sets the V,N,S,Z flags, but SUBI sets H,V,N,S,Z,C. Since the compiler generated a TST instruction next, it appears not to be using the flags from the SUBI anyway. Also, using a SUBI seems odd because an ADDI with 0x01 would be equivalent again. It's sort of a mystery really.

Comment: I just noticed there is no ADDI instruction. Perhaps that explains part of it.

Comment: @GregHewgill I've taken the liberty to (of course feel free to rollback if you wish) expand your answer; since you basically hit the nail with the flags here, I've added some links, rationale etc. to substantiate it. I didn't want to post another answer since you basically answered it already, yet I felt that your answer would be better with a bit more behind-the-scenes compiler trivia.

Comment: @vaxquis: that code is probably from `gcc -O0`, right?  Otherwise gcc would be smart enough to skip the `tst` and branch on flags set by `subi`.

Comment: @vaxquis: yeah, I look at gcc asm output all the time on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ (which includes an [ancient AVR-gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/17krjp)), I just don't have experience with AVR.

Comment: @PeterCordes my avr-gcc 4.9.2 emits almost identical assembly, at least for this example; anyway, in the general case, it's just like you said: even at `-O1`, it's just `subi r17,lo8(-(1))` and immediately `brne .L3`, without any additional `sts` nor `tst` (https://godbolt.org/g/ieM6PJ)